# How do you add numbers to an int?

Tags: c#, winforms, int

I'm trying to make a basic calculator in c#.

The only problem is, I don't know how I could add numbers to an int; for instance, if I wanted button1 to do something like this in a textbox, it'd be

```
textBox1.text += "1"
```

but this is for the operations, and the textbox displays the operator, so I couldn't convert it to an int. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with something like (where `s` is a string):

```
s = (Int32.Parse(s) + 1).ToString();
```

Just make sure that `s` is actually a valid number, otherwise you'll have to cobble together something with `TryParse` and figure out what to do when it's *not* a number, like leave it alone:

```
int val;
if (Int32.TryParse(s, out val)) {
    val++;
    s = val.ToString();
}
```

You can also restrict user input so that they can only enter integers, have a look at `MaskedTextBox` and set the `Mask` property. See [the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

C# is a strongly typed language. A textbox contains a `string`, which you must convert to an `int` before performing arithmetical operations.

Converting a string to an int can be done with `int.Parse()`, then you must convert back to a string to change the textbox contents:

```
int temp = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + 1;
textBox1.Text = temp.ToString();
```

This will throw an exception if `textBox.Text` cannot be converted to an `int`. To deal with this, look up the `int.TryParse()` function.

Comment: Chris, you can do code _blocks_ by putting four spaces at the start of each line (or marking the text and doing CTRL-K). I've made the change to your block so it doesn't bunch up on one line. If you edit to see what I've done (and cancel), that should hopefully help you out in future. Cheers.